# Can you run a terminal emulator under a tty?

Tags: terminal, tty, terminal-emulator

I would like to know if you can run a terminal emulator under a tty since I just started the program alacritty. If there is a way, no matter how hard it would seem, I would like to try it, a tty is so convenient and alacritty is so cool that I would love to see what would be the results of running alacritty under a tty session.

Comment: I’m a bit confused by what you are asking for. Alacritty is a graphical application that runs under X. It runs a tty (pty really) already, since it is a terminal emulator. What are you describing for running it under a tty session.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

OP's probably referring to a Linux [*virtual console*](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/linux-virtual-console-and-terminal-explained.html).  A *terminal emulator* in the sense referred to is a *graphical program*, which would not run in a *text* display.

A terminal emulator has wider use than graphical applications.  Some people consider [*screen*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) and [*tmux*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) to be terminal emulators.  Quoting from the former:

> ***Screen*** is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a
> physical terminal between several processes (typically
> interactive shells).  Each *virtual terminal* provides the
> functions of a DEC VT100 terminal and, in addition, several
> control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA 48, ANSI X3.64) and ISO
> 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and support for multiple
> character sets).  There is a scrollback history buffer for each
> virtual terminal and a copy-and-paste mechanism that allows
> moving text regions between windows.
> Those run inside a terminal (or emulator), and would run in a virtual console (which is actually a terminal emulator anyway, since it is a computer program).

A graphical terminal emulator could be run in a virtual console by switching it to a graphical mode, e.g., with the [SDL library](https://www.libsdl.org/).  On a related note, a few terminal emulators have been written using the Linux framebuffer ([apparently](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/can-sdl2-still-use-the-linux-framebuffer/20083) a different mechanism), e.g., [jfbterm](https://jfbterm.osdn.jp/).  The X Window System by the way switches a virtual console (typically `tty7`) to graphical mode.  So when you are running Alacritty, it is "really" in `tty7`.

For X applications, you can start a terminal emulator, e.g., from `tty3` and display (and use) it on the X display running in a different tty:

```
xterm -display :1
```

Incidentally, not everything running ***on*** an X display is an X application.  As I recall it, [Alacritty](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Alacritty) (using [OpenGL](https://techpubs.jurassic.nl/manuals/0530/developer/OpenGL_Porting/sgi_html/ch04.html)) is not.

Comment: I would like to add that I am using wayland as my backend for graphical applications, thank you for the detailed response though!